# Should we comment on voting to close?

Tags: discussion

Quite often we see posts that were put on hold for various reasons without any comment on the question.

Canned close reasons are mostly self-explaining (or at least they should be) but I sometimes feel that an individual user who took time to contribute here with writing a question should deserve some individual treatment.

In addition new users may not be aware of many aspects of our quality requirements. For them it would be vital to learn what is wrong with their post to avoid closing, which could lead to a question ban.

Therefore I would like to hear what our policy should be. Should moderators write a comment after a closure (we get an auto-flag for this reason)? Should the close voters take their time to comment? Should we comment whenever we see a question caught a close vote irrespective of our agreement with the close reason?

Comment: It should be noted that we only get an auto-flag if a question was closed without any comment. A considerable amount of questions gets closed with some comment that does not explain the closure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only describe my own policy:

It is fair and useful to give a comment with a close vote (If the question already has a close vote with a valid reason you agree to, you don't need to bother with an additional comment) - How else should the OP know what he can do to improve his questioning?

For some questions, however, where you can easily see the OP hasn't put the slightest effort into his question, I don't really see a reason why *the close-voter* should invest more effort into commenting a vote than what was originally put into the question.

(Same applies to downvotes on both questions and answers, BTW. It's only fair to comment *why* you downvote, as long as it isn't very obvious)